# passing value through pointer to void

Tags: c

The snippet passes the value of `id` to a routine that takes a general `void *` structure.  I am confused as to *why* it works: why can you cast the `long` to `void*` and cast it back with a `long`.

In particular, I was thinking if you want to pass by pointer, then you should pass the address of the variable such as `&id` to the `test()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void * id) {
    long myid;
    myid = (long) id;
    printf("my id is %ld\n", myid);
}

int main() {
    long id = 5;
    test( (void *)id);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, because (on your system!) the `void*` pointer itself contains enough bits to hold all bits of a `long` value. This is not portable.

You're right that you'd normally cast a `long*` to `void*` and back. That is portable.

Answer (score 1):

It works because pointers are just numbers.

Your test function "thinks" it received a pointer to memory location 5, and you can of course print this address. You wouldn't be able to assign anything to this location, so *myid = 42 would cause a segmentation fault. Casting a number to a pointer is syntactically correct so your compiler won't moan but it doesn't make any sense.  Run this code and see how a pointer looks when printed (ignore the warning from your compiler).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void *id, long *foo) {
    long myid;
    myid = (long) id;
    printf("my id is %ld, %ld\n", myid, foo);
}

int main() {
    long id = 5;
    long foo;
    foo = 42;
    test( (void *)id, &foo);
}
```

Comment: That is not correct way to print value of `foo`. Either use `printf("%p", (void*)foo); /* better */` or `printf("%ld", (long)foo); /* worse */`

Comment: Pointers are not "just numbers". Famously, 8086 "far" pointers are _two_ numbers. (Segment/offset)

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused as to why it works: why can you cast the long to void* and cast it back with a long.

```
long id = 5;
test( (void *)id);
```

This is actually valid. You basically mean to pass a `void` pointer to function `test`, that pointer holds the address of `5`.

In `void test(void * id)`, you cast that pointer back to `long` which is also valid.

Note in your code you never deference the pointer so things work. If you do dereference the pointer `id` in `test`, that would usually lead to segfault due to bad memory access.